# How to download a file from a VDI (citrix workspace) Artifactory through Python

Tags: python, python-requests, artifactory

I have a question regarding VDI, Artifactory, and Python.
I wanted to download an artifact that I have tested inside the VDI with the command:

```
curl https://artifactory-aaaa.company.com/artifactory/artifacts/browse/tree/General/thedirectory/results/filename.xml --output filename.xml
```

It outputs an XML file, just what I wanted.

I tried doing the same with the Python requests module on my computer (download.py):

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://artifactory-aaaa.company.com/artifactory/artifacts/browse/tree/General/thedirectory/results/filename.xml')
with open("filename.xml", "wb") as file:
    file.write(r.content)
```

and it returns an error :

```
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x03A4CA50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

then

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='artifactory-scanner.asml.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /artifactory/artifacts/browse/tree/General/thedirectory/results/filename.xml (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x03A4CA50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

To access these file I am required to connect to a VPN. I am connected to the VPN and are able to get the data inside the VDI. But during my Python run, it does not connect. Anybody know what seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error snippet shared during the artifact download from the Artifactory application, it looks like there is a connectivity issue from the client(your computer) to Artifactory. You can validate the connectivity using the telnet from your computer to connect to the Artifactory IP/port.

Also, you can validate the Artifactory request logs to check whether the request is reaching the application or not.